# Launching a python script in IDLE works but in terminal I get a SMTP instance has no attribute 'send_message' error

Tags: python3, smtp, idle-python

I have a script that results in an email being sent out with `smtplib.SMTP` python module.

When I run it from within IDLE is sends fine with no error messages. I am trying various ways to automate it with crontab to go everyday at 10am.

If I run it from terminal, I get an error:

```
$ python endofmonth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "endofmonth.py", line 74, in <module>
    s.send_message(msg)
AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Why would it work in IDLE but not when called from terminal?

Answer (score 3):

[The `send_message` method to `SMTP` class was added in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message). You are calling the script to be run using `python` which is a symlink for Python 2. Since `send_message` method is not defined in Python 2, you get an `AttributeError`.

To get over this, you need to call your script using Python 3.2 or newer. Run it as:

```
python3 endofmonth.py
```

and it would work.

You are most probably using the Python 3 version of IDLE which is the reason it works there.